# Solr expand search only returns the first 5 rows

Tags: solr

I have the following Solr query:

```
http://local:8983/solr/select?start=0&rows=1000&
      q=id:5332527&
      expand=true&expand.q=param_name_s:s21mag&expand.field=_root_
```

In the response, it shows that 1000 records were found.  However, Solr only returns the first 5 rows. As you can see, I included `start=0&rows=1000`, but that did not help.

How do I force Solr to return all 1000 rows?

Answer (score 3):

> `expand.rows`  The number of rows to display in each group. Default is 5.

You need to include the `expand.rows` parameter in the query to get the desired number of results.

Reference: [Collapse and Expand Results](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results)

Comment: Thank you @YoungHobbit.  Your answer is exactly what I looked for.  I searched the web for the whole day but could not find the solution.  Thank you again for your help.